# Accessing values in a JSON response

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-requests

I'm using Python requests and am trying to access the values that I am getting from a GET request that I have made. The output is a JSON response (I think it's called a 2D array as there are arrays within the array). I want to store these values so that I can access them in the next function.

Here is the Python:

```
import requests
import json

def getAllSpices():
    url = str("https://prod-api.texau.com/api/spices")

    payload={}
    user_input = input("Please enter your APIKey ") 
    headers = {
        'Authorization': user_input
    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    jsResponse = response.json()

    print(jsResponse)

getAllSpices()
```

Here is the output:

```
{'scripts': [{'id': '609d239bee870923f3436af5', 'name': 'Find Emails using Domain', 
'description': 'Find emails corresponding to a domain. Uses 4 email credits. Max. 100 emails', 
'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 'email', 'tags': ['New']}, {'id': '6093e35a60c1c5f6fb0be491', 
'name': 'Extract Attendees from a LinkedIn Event', 'description': 'Extract a list of attendees 
from a LinkedIn event', 'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 
'linkedin', 'tags': []}, {'id': '6075a33ba98f6137332e6b39', 'name': 'Extract saved accounts 
list from Sales Navigator', 'description': 'Extract companies from saved accounts lists on 
LinkedIn Sales Navigator', 
'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 'linkedin', 'tags': []}, {'id': '602e40ca4d75d30ce66a18d8', 
'name': 'Scrape products from ProductHunt', 'description': 'Extract products from 
ProductHunt', 'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 'productHunt', 'tags': ['New']}, {'id': 
'602505b104f18d32530386b0', 'name': 'Scrape search results from Google', 'description': 
'Extract information about a search text from Google', 'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 'google', 
'tags': ['New']}, {'id': '602505b304f18d3253038706', 'name': 'Extract reviews from Google Play 
 Store', 'description': 'Extract reviews of an application on Google Play Store', 'owner': 
'admin', 'platform': 'google', 'tags': ['New']}, {'id': '602505b104f18d32530386ad', 'name': 
'Scrape trends on Google', 'description': 'Extract trends information from Google based on 
keywords', 'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 'google', 'tags': ['New']}, {'id': 
'6023d67a04f18d3253bb04ef', 'name': 'Scrape a Pinterest profile', 'description': 'Scrape a 
pinterest profile', 'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 'pinterest', 'tags': ['New']}, {'id': 
'6022819ba69458b9c716c03e', 'name': 'Take screenshot of a 
Facebook Page or profile', 'description': 'Take a screenshot of profile and profile picture', 
'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 'facebook', 'tags': ['New']}, {'id': '6021493fa69458b9c7da5ed4', 
'name': 'Like or Retweet A Tweet', 'description': 'Like, Retweet or Both a Tweet on Twitter', 
'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 'twitter', 'tags': ['New']}, {'id': '5ffc5d308f33b5712b9589b5', 
'name': 'Extract LinkedIn Conversation Links', 'description': 'Extract all the conversation 
thread urls from your LinkedIn account', 'owner': 'admin', 'platform': 'linkedin', 'tags': 
[]}, {'id': '5f687f22b6e15b13ffbe05aa', 'name': 'Extract Friends of a 
Facebook profile New', 'description': 'Extract Friends of a Facebook profile', 'owner': 
'admin', 'platform': 'facebook', 'tags': ['New UI']}], 'success': True, 'done': False, 
'total': 143}
```

For example, I'd like to store 'id' of each of the inner arrays and then pass those ids into the next function that will get information about the ids.

Comment: Once you call `response.json()`, you don't have to think about JSON anymore. That method is returning an ordinary `dict`, which you treat like any other dict. `jsResponse['scripts']`, for example, is a `list`.

Comment: okay so I just changed the second last line to 

 print(jsResponse['id'])

then I got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\01_Documents\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.py", line 19, in <module>
    getAllSpices()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive\01_Documents\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.py", line 17, in getAllSpices
    print(jsResponse['id'])
KeyError: 'id'

I've read that KeyError: 'id' error means that 'id' wasnt found right? But you can see 'id' in the response

Comment: That's because `id` is not a key of `jsReponse`. It's a key in an *element* of the list `jsResponse['scripts']`.

Comment: wow I completely missed scripts at the beginning. Thank you. So I just changed it to the below:

print(jsResponse['scripts'][0]['id'])

and got the id number yay! Now I think I'm on my way thank you :)

Comment: I am however only getting the first id. Would an if statement work to iterate over the array for all ids?

Comment: No, you need a loop of some kind. I suggest spending some time with [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). Nothing you are asking about is specific to JSON or HTTP APIs. You've already dealt with all that; you just need to work with an ordinary Python value now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ids of the jsResponse, just do:

```
list_of_ids = list(map(lambda x: x["id"], jsResponse['scripts']))
```

or even easily, using list comprehension:

```
list_of_ids = [x['id'] for x in jsResponse['scripts']]
```

Comment: Just to be clear, `map` does not return a list; it's an iterable class, so you could create a list using `list(map(...))`.

Comment: list comprehension is working perfectly thank you :)